# Java opening File Streams in one class and closing/deletion of file in another class

Tags: java, file, stream

I want to delete the file which is opened and done writing but not closed. Please refer to code below:

Class A (can't be changed):

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class A {

    public void run(String file) throws Exception {
        FileOutputStream s = new FileOutputStream(file);

    }
}
```

Class B:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String path = "D:\\CONFLUX_HOME\\TestClient\\Maps\\test\\newTest.txt";
        A a = new A();
        a.run(path);
        File f = new File(path);
        Files.delete(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()));

    }

}
```

In Class A , just open the stream without closing the file.
In class B , calling A's run method and then try to delete the file.
Since the file is still opened. I'm unable to delete the file.

Error is :
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Actual Scenario is :
We are loading the jars dynamically. Classes inside jar are creating the file. When there is an exception, a file gets created whose size will be 0 bytes. We need to delete this file. Since the file is not closed during the exception, we can't delete the file.

We could fix the issue if we could close the streams in the jar classes, but we can't modify the jars that create the files as they are client specific jars.

Please suggest how to delete the opened file, without modifying the code in class A.

Comment: There is no way to access the stream opened by `A`?

Comment: which operating system ?

Comment: @user3360241: Sounds like Windows, Unix systems don't have those restrictions.

Comment: @Sharath I rephrased the question a bit to make the issue a little clearer as I understand it - please check it's still correct, and revert my edits otherwise.

Comment: yes tomcat and jboss on windows and unix.

Comment: @Cupawntae-  thanks for editing.Now question is very clearer

Comment: The antiResourceLocking option should fix file issues on windows. On Linux this should not be happening anyway as Unix-like operating systems do not normally automatically lock open files or running programs.

Comment: @Sharath Do you have the option of using a different filename each time? E.g. add a timestamp or counter into the filename. Then at some point in the future, find and delete the zero-byte files left behind.

Comment: @Sharath if you don't find a pure java solution another option that might work would be to install something like http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/ and exec its command line from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close the file, even if there was an Exception when writing to it.

E.g.

```
public void run(String file) throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream s = null;
    try {
        s = new FileOutputStream(file);    
    } finally {
        try {
            s.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // log this exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My understanding was OP is not allowed to modify jars which make files hang, therefore the answer should show how to do that outside problematic jars.

Comment: @user3360241: Then the OP needs to provide the relevant code for that case. The answer is as specific as it can get, provided the information given by the OP.

Comment: It's not clear from the question that this is the case.  If they don't have access to the code, then I think a simple solution would be to wait for the streams to be garbage-collected before deleting the file.

Comment: Problem will be if the streams are referenced in some singletons managed by the Container ?

Comment: class A should not be modified

Comment: @Sharath please update the question.  And consider waiting for GC.

Comment: @Sharath if you do consider waiting for GC you could call `System.gc()` to try to encourage the JVM to expedite it. But I would keep GC as a last resort because it won't be deterministic - you'll need some kind of wait-retry loop, and something to avoid hanging indefinitely. And it will fail altogether if the streams are being referenced persistently anywhere in the jar code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the file before any delete operation as firstly its a bad practice and second is it will lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tomcat, it is possible to set AntiLockingOption and  antiJARLocking in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml for Windows:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true" >
```

**Important note:**

The antiResourceLocking option can stop JSPs from redeploying when they are edited requiring a redeploy.

Read more about this option:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

**antiResourceLocking:**

If true, Tomcat will prevent any file locking. This will significantly impact startup time of applications, but allows full webapp hot deploy and undeploy on platforms or configurations where file locking can occur. If not specified, the default value is false.

Answer (score 0):

Updated according to OPs comment.
Another approach could be to subclass A and override `run()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        String path = "D:\\CONFLUX_HOME\\TestClient\\Maps\\test\\newTest.txt";


        A a = new A() {
            @Override
            public void run(String file) throws Exception {
                FileOutputStream s = new FileOutputStream(file);
                s.close();
            }
        };
        a.run(path);

        File f = new File(path);

        Files.delete(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()));
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
```

Comment: Class A should not be modified.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe there is an approach to access the FileOutputStream directly, if class A has weak encapsulation. In your example this won't work though.

Comment: @Sharath updated answer. This might be an option, if you're allowed to subclass A.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the resource as a parameter and it becomes the caller's responsibility to clear up the resources

```
   public void run(FileOutputStream stream) throws Exception {
     ...
   }
```

caller:

```
try(FileStream stream = new FileStream(path)){
      A a = new A();
      a.run(stream);
}catch(Exception e){
  .. exception handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find a pure java solution to this problem. One option is to install [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) (being careful to hit "Skip" on all the junkware) and invoke it from your code.

If you have UAC enabled, you'll also need to be running your java in an elevated process (e.g. start command prompt as Administrator). Then, assuming unlocker is in `C:\Program Files\Unlocker`:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("c:\\Program Files\\Unlocker\\Unlocker.exe",path,"-s").start();
p.waitFor();
```

And after that you can delete the file as before. Or you could use `"-d"` instead of `"-s"` and Unlocker will delete the file for you.